# Exponential and Gamma Distribution: Component Failure Question

Tags: statistics

> Suppose that under normal operating conditions, the operating time until failure of a certain type of component has exponential($\lambda$) distribution for some $\lambda > 0$. And suppose that the random variables representing lifetimes of different components of this type may be regarded as independent.
>
> Given the average lifetime of 10,000 components is found to be 20 days. Estimate the value of $\lambda$ based on this information

[image]

**Textbook Answer:**

[image]

Comment: Textbook answers are indeed sometimes wrong, you are entitled to some skepticism, and this is a good place for ask for a reality check. (+1) But this time I think the answer provided is correct. See the rationale in my answer.

Comment: You may have missed "average" in "the average lifetime of 10,000 components is found to be 20 days". The phrase means that $$\frac{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{10,000}}{10,000}=20$$ where $X_k$ denotes the lifetime, measured in days, of component $k$. The rest follows.

Comment: @Did I did address that, $E(S) = $expected lifetime of$ 10,000  $components$ = $average lifetime of$ 10,000  $components $=20$

Comment: @A_for_Abacus No, your post explicitely mistakes the sum for the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X_i \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\text{rate} = \lambda).$ Then
$T = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\sim \mathsf{Gamma}(\text{shape}=n,\, \text{rate}=\lambda)$
and $\bar X = \frac T n \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(\text{shape}=n,\, \text{rate}=n\lambda).$ Thus for $n$ observations, we have $E(X_i) = \frac{1}{\lambda},\,$
$E(T) = \frac{n}{\lambda},\,$ and $E(\bar X) = \frac{1}{\lambda}.$ [I'm using $T$ instead of $S$ because $S$ should be reserved notation for the sample standard deviation.]

However, $\hat \lambda = \frac n T $ is not an unbiased estimator of $\lambda.$
The following simulation suggests (does not *prove*) that $\check \lambda = \frac{n-1}{T}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\lambda,$ whereas $\hat \lambda = \frac n T$ is not. Formal proofs of the above relationships are via moment generating functions and (in the case of $E(\check \lambda)$) integration.

```
set.seed(318) # retain seed statement for exactly same simulation, omit for fresh run
m = 10^6;  n = 5;  lam = 1/10
t = replicate(m,  sum(rexp(n, lam)))
mean(t); mean(t/n); mean(n/t);  mean((n-1)/t)
## 49.99976   # aprx E(T) = 50
## 9.999951   # aprx E(avg) = 10
## 0.1250256  # n/T NOT unbiased for lambda 
## 0.1000204  # suggests E((n-1)/T) = lambda
```

However, for $n$ as large as 10,000, the bias of $\hat \lambda$ is
negligible in most practical applications. So if $\bar X = T/n= 20,$
then $1/ \hat \lambda = n/T = 1/\bar X = 1/20$ is a reasonable (even if *very slightly biased*) estimate of $\lambda.$

The figure below illustrates that the sample mean $\bar X = \frac T n \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(\text{shape}=n,\, \text{rate}=n\lambda),$ as mentioned above;
the gamma PDF is superimposed on a histogram of the simulated values of $\bar X.$

[image]

Comment: This does not address the question at all, does it?

Comment: "Hardly a helpful comment" Helpful or not, you choose to not address it. "Would you like to share yours?" I did.

Comment: Again, I already addressed what the OP is really asking, on this page. You are so worried to "defend" your answer that you are losing all common sense, it seems... Just relax, nobody is "attacking" you here.

Comment: Guess I'm just missing your point. How does my "$\bar X = T/n= 20,$" differ from what you say in your Comment (except for notation)? Ordinarily that would also suggest $E(X_i) \approx 20.$ But something's still not clear to OP and I can't figure out what.

Comment: It is not, the difference is that now (after my comment on main), we now know this confusion (or rather, the omission of the word "average" in the text) was the source of the OP's trouble. See, there was no need for this furious reaction of yours...

Comment: Hardly 'furious', just succinct. No more succinct than "does not address the question at all." Maybe we need emojis. We've been busted for chatting in Comments. Signing off. Have a nice day or night or whatever it is where you are.

Comment: Rewriting history, and rather tediously at that? Not nice.